# SQL Server execution plan Index seek

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I was trying to improve 2 queries that are almost the same with indexing. I saw a Table Scan in the first query and created an index to make that an Index Seek, when I saw the second query, SQL Server indicated to create an index equals that last I have created changing the order of columns only, but in execution plan the SQL Server Engine was already doing an Index seek on the table.

My question is:

If SQL Server execution plan are already an index seek should I create another index for this query, should I delete the index I have created and replace with this other one, or should I ignore the advice that SQL Server gives?

Comment: Does query 2 run at an acceptable speed after adding the first index?

Comment: @Simon yes, it run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot answer without specific details. This is not a guessing game. Please post the exact table structure, table sizes, the indexes you added and the execution plans you have.

The fact that you added *an* index does not mean you added the *best* index. Nor  does the fact that the execution plan uses an index seek implies the plan is *optimal*. Wrong index column order and partial predicate match would manifest as 'seek' on the leading column(s), it would be suboptimal, and SQL would continue recommending a better index (ie. exactly the symptoms you describe).

Please read [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/) and [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Comment: i know that just cause is an index seek that not means that is perfect, but i was considering that is already good than why should i create other index just to be a little better?

Answer (score 0):

> I saw a Table Scan in the first query and created an index to make that an Index Seek

**All Seeks are not good,All Scans are not bad..**

Imagine you have an customers table with 10 customers each having 1000 orders,now total rows in the orders table is 10000 rows..

To get  top 1 order for each customer ,if your query is doing scan of orders table it may be bad,since doing seek will only cost you 10 seeks..

You have to  understand the data and see why optimizer choose this plan and how you make optimizer in choosing the plan you need..Itzik Ben-Gan gives amazing [examples in this tutoria](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/seek-and-you-shall-scan-part-i-when-optimizer-doesnt-optimize)l  and there is a [video on SQL Bits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vz5JmccTEKU)

Further Craig Freedman talks on seeks and scans part and goes into details on  why [optimiser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/tag/scans-and-seeks/) may choose Scan over Seek  due to random reads,data density

Comment: Thanks, i will see the links you posted.